# Stochastic Convergence - Radford Neal's Prior

Tags: machine-learning, probability, covariance, central-limit-theorem, stochastic-approximation

There's question 1.3 in [this set of questions](https://alex.smola.org/teaching/10-701-15/homework/hw3_sol.pdf) already solved I found about stochastic convergence.

I cannot understand where the expression $$\sum_{i} \phi_{i}^{2}(x)$$ came from and why is the last covariance derivation is $$\leq \frac{C^{2}}{3}$$ right at the last step.

**Here's the question and its solution, which I find unclear.**

Assume that we have some function

$$
f_{n}(x):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_{i} \phi_{i}(x)
$$

that is being evaluated on points $x_{1}, \ldots x_{m} .$ Assume that the weights $\alpha_{i}$ are drawn iid from the uniform distribution $U[-1,1],$ and that all $\phi_{i}$ are bounded in their $L_{\infty}$ norm, i.e. $\left|\phi_{i}(x)\right| \leq C$ for some constant $C .$ Analyze the convergence of the vector $\left(f_{n}\left(x_{1}\right) \ldots f_{n}\left(x_{m}\right)\right)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty .$ Hint: you can invoke the central limit theorem. Can you derive a condition on the covariance between two function values $f_{n}\left(x_{i}\right) f_{n}\left(x_{j}\right)$ ?

**Solution:**

We can apply the central limit theorem,
$$
f_{n}(x) \sim N\left(0, \frac{1}{3} \sum_{i} \phi_{i}^{2}(x)\right)
$$

where $\frac{1}{3}$ is the variance of the uniform distribution of $\alpha_{i}$ on the range [-1,1] . The covariance between $f\left(x_{i}\right)$ and $f\left(x_{j}\right)$ can be derived as follows (assuming that the mean of $\mathrm{f}(\mathrm{x})$ is 0 ):

$$
\begin{aligned}
E\left[f\left(x_{i}\right) f\left(x_{j}\right)\right] &=\frac{1}{n} E\left[\sum_{k} \alpha_{i k} \phi_{i k}\left(x_{i}\right) \sum_{i} \alpha_{j i} \phi_{j i}\left(x_{j}\right)\right] \\
&=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k} \sum_{i} E\left[\alpha_{i k} \alpha j i \phi_{j i}\left(x_{j}\right)\right] \\
&=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k} \sum_{l} E\left[\alpha_{i k}^{2} \phi_{i k}\left(x_{i}\right)^{2}\right] \\
&=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k} \phi_{i k}\left(x_{i}\right)^{2} E\left[\alpha_{k}^{2}\right] \\
&=\frac{1}{3 n} \sum_{k} \phi_{i k}\left(x_{i}\right)^{2} \\
& \leq \frac{C^{2}}{3}
\end{aligned}
$$